# Raster attribute table not showing up after exporting from R

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, r, attribute-table

I exported a categorical raster from R and loaded it into ArcMap to visualize it. However, the attribute table is greyed out.

Code In R:
I first tell R that the values are factors by ratifying it.

```
lulc_1985.resam <- ratify(lulc_1985.resam)
rat1985 <- data.frame(
  ID= 1:11,
  LandCover = c("Deciduous","Cropland", "Settlement","Mixed Forest",
                "Scrubland","Barren Land","Wetlands","Plantations",
                "Coastal","Grassland","Evergreen")
)
levels(lulc_1985.resam)<- rat1985
```

The output of the above:

```
> lulc_1985.resam
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 203, 192, 38976  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent      : 628560.6, 820560.6, 1084984, 1287984  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 1, 11  (min, max)
attributes  :
       ID LandCover
 from:  1 Deciduous
 to  : 11 Evergreen
```

As you can see above, the attributes exist here. Now I export the same out of R:

```
writeRaster(lulc_1985.resam,"E:\\lulc_1985.tif", format="GTiff")
```

The raster is now visualized in ArcMap, where the attribute table is greyed out.

[image]

How do I retrieve this attribute table?

The exported .tif is just 13kb in size.

Comment: Rasters do not have an attribute table - the values are coded directly into each individual pixel.

Comment: Have you tried building a raster attribute table in ArcGIS?: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-raster-attribute-table.htm